# Making RSA Encryption Java Program Independent of Platform

Tags: java, encryption, jar, rsa

I have created a GUI Java Program to decrypt files using RSA keys.

However, the encryption has been done on IBM AIX Machine which have used IBM JCE Provider.

Now, I will generate a jar file of the decrytion again on the same platform i.e. AIX Machine.

My question is that, whether that jar file will work fine on windows machines? as on windows JCE Providers are SUN JCE not IBM JCE.

Or I will have to install that IBM JCE on the machine where Jar is required to be executed?

Comment: You could actually try it.

Comment: If your code specifies an IBM provider by name, it will not work on a JVM using  Oracle/OpenJDK providers. If you only specify the algorithm and let JCA find the provider, both the IBM providers and the Oracle/OpenJDK providers implement RSA and should be interoperable unless you specified something unusual in the transform, like a weird padding.

Answer (score 2):

Basically most providers are made to be compatible with the Sun/Oracle implementations that they provide. That means that if you specify an algorithm that is within the [list of provided algorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html) then it is usually compatible. If it is in the list of [Java implementation requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#security-algorithm-implementation-requirements) then you can be virtually certain.

The IBM JCA implementation is basically a re-hash of the one provided by Oracle. I'd not copy the `.jar` unless you have no other option. The Java Cryptography Architecture was explicitly specified for the user calls to be provider agnostic, so you should try and make it work without requiring an external library.

Note that many algorithms within the JCA are using hardware accelerated instructions such as AES-NI, so using the OpenJDK/Sun/Oracle implementations can give a nice speedup.

There are a few ways of having a larger chance of being compatible:

- do not specify a specific provider;
- don't use a specific name for a random number generator (use `new SecureRandom()` or the thread local random number generator);
- don't use different names than the algorithms in the list, e.g. don't use the more logical `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"` or `"AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"` but keep to `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` and `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` even though they make less sense;
- do always create and specify the IV for block cipher modes other than ECB, because the provider specific IV may be either all zero or randomized;
- don't use provider specific parameter / parameter specs, key stores etc.
- use the key sizes supported by the Java implementation requirements, or at least those provided by the OpenJDK providers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have used RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding for encryption which executed on windows under sun provider but when I executed it on IBM machine for decryption with same padding. It shows Decryption error due to different provider because IBM machine use IBM JCE

Comment: Thats more likely a different error such as using a wrong key but you wil have to post the code  for us  top find out.  In a separate question please.